# What does the export PATH line in .bashrc do?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I am not so into Linux and I have the following doubt following a tutorial.

I have to modify the `bashrc` file. What kind of settings are contained in this file? I think something related the bash shell environment but I am not so sure about it.

I have to insert this line:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.local/usr/bin:$PATH
```

What exactly does this line?

I think that `export` statement is used to create a new variable making it available for other program.

But what exactly does this line? Is `PATH` the name of the variable that I am defining? What is `$HOME`?

What means the `:` symbol between `PATH=$HOME/.local/bin` and `$HOME/.local/usr/bin` and `$PATH` section in the previous expression?

What exactly does this expression mean?

Comment: The : between the items is the separator for each segment.  Without it, your path would be one continuous run on and would not work.

Comment: In Ubuntu this kind of `PATH` modifications is already done in the `~/.profile` file, so it's a little inconsistent to do similar stuff in `~/.bashrc`. Better IMO to modify the code already in `~/.profile` if needed. Currently the default `~/.profile` file includes this line: `PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: There are some situations that make .profile and .bashrc different. The file .profile is parsed by login shells and not by subshells. But since you need to login anyway to start a subshell this is OK since subshells will inherit $PATH. The .bashrc file will not be parsed by the login shell but will be parsed by subshells. The difference comes when you have some stuff that are not children of login shells (maybe some fancy automation script that calls other scripts like git commit hook) - anything in .profile will not be read so they will be ignored

Comment: @slebetman: Right, and in case of a desktop there is another difference which you don't mention: Unlike `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` is sourced by the display manager, so only variables set by `~/.profile` are available when you start programs from the graphical environment. And that happens early so it should be ok for autostarted processes for the session.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To recap everything mentioned in this question,

#### The `export` part

The `export` line means that the variable that you declare after it will be accessible to child processes. In other words, processes will be able to access the variable declared after the `export` keyword through the shell's environment. So, if you did something like `export FOO="BAR"` and then sourced the changes in your shell environment, you could type `$FOO` and get `BAR`.

#### The `PATH` part

The path line is just as you stated: it's declaring a variable that's named `PATH` for the shell environment. In the bash environment, `PATH` has a special purpose of defining where the computer looks for programs is. This lets you type custom commands for scripts without typing the full directory. *Note that PATH is marked for export by default, so this line doesn't have to be rewritten. It doesn't hurt, though.*

#### The `$HOME` in the `PATH` variable

At the beginning of the path that is assigned to the `PATH` variable, `$HOME` is declared. This means that the computer will pretty much grab the value stored in `HOME` and copy-paste it in front of the rest of the line when reading it.

#### The `:` in between both paths

The `:` is equivalent to a comma in sentences. It just separates the three directories. Without those three directories, the console would not recognize the commands it receives. Those three places are the three directories that are most commonly used for scripts/command files to be stored and therefore should be accessible by the terminal without having to write out the full path to the file.

Comment: Great answer!

"The export line means that the variable that you declare after it will be accessible to child processes" is the parent for these child processes the terminal from where I will run a command ?

Answer (score 6):

The `PATH` variable lets bash know where to look for executable programs, so if you have a script or some other executable file in `$HOME/.local/bin` , modifying `PATH` will let you type and run that file just like you do with `ls` or `df`.

`export` only means to make that `PATH` variable also available for other programs you run from bash.

As for `:`  , it's just a separator for each directory. It's the same as a comma in a list of words, nothing more.